# Edit WordPress Header using Elementor

Tags: wordpress

I have started building services website on WordPress. I want to edit header of my [junk removal services in mclean](https://www.majunk.com/junk-removal-in-mclean/) website. Can someone help me out? I can provide the link to the website if needed.

Comment: Add more information about the problem, what are you trying to achieve and what you did to get there. and the link also

Comment: From what is remember. Header and Footer templates are only available for elementor pro. If you have the pro version their documentation cover how to do it. [Check elementor header/footer builder](https://elementor.com/blog/header-footer-builder/)